# OpenGL colors with index buffer object

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a cube, with 8 vertices, and I want a different color for every face, I can do this with VBO's by coloring every triangle, and passing a color to a vertice more than 1 time.

But with index buffer object, I can only pass 1 color to each vertex, so how can I color every face ?

```
GLuint createCube()
{
const float vertices[] = {
    0.25f, 0.25f, -1.25f, 1.0f,
    0.25f, -0.25f, -1.25f, 1.0f,
    -0.25f, 0.25f, -1.25f, 1.0f,
    -0.25f, -0.25f, -1.25f, 1.0f,
    0.25f, 0.25f, -2.75f, 1.0f,
    -0.25f, 0.25f, -2.75f, 1.0f,
    0.25f, -0.25f, -2.75f, 1.0f,
    -0.25f, -0.25f, -2.75f, 1.0f,

            // 8 colors for 8 vertices!
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,

    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
};

const GLint indexData[]
{
        0, 1, 2,
        1, 3, 2,
        4, 5, 6,
        6, 5, 7,
        2, 3, 7,
        2, 7, 5,
        0, 6, 1,
        0, 4, 6,
        4, 0, 2,
        4, 2, 5,
        6, 3, 1,
        6, 7, 3,
};

GLuint vao;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);

GLuint vbo;
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);

GLuint indexObjectBuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &indexObjectBuffer);

glBindVertexArray(vao);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexObjectBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 36*4, indexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)128);

glBindVertexArray(0);

return vao;
}
```

#### Output:

[image: Output]

As you see the front face is blue and back is red, and the other faces are blended. How can I give the other faces specific colors ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colours are per-vertex, not per-face, so your best shot is to duplicate vertices in the VBO. One vertex is the whole set of data (position, colour, normal vector, texture coords...) If you need some of the data to be different, then technically you have 2 different vertices rather than one.

You might, however, hack that around by taking the face colour from the first vertex instead of using smooth shading.

Comment: Why "hack"? It's explicitely provided by the spec: use a `flat` interpolation qualifier for the color (as output in the vertex shader and input in the fragment shader) -- that will make the rasterizer not interpolate that value. Instaed, it will pick the value of the *provoking vertex* (the first or the last of the triangle, see `glProvokingVertex` docs).

Comment: So duplicating vertices is the only way ? I've done this : http://pastebin.com/n9ruKYcq and it works now. There are 3 times more vertices now.

Comment: @peppe It depends a little on your viewpoint... If you are used to WebGL/ES 2.0 or GL 2.1, which do not have interpolation qualifiers, then it surely feels like a "hack". Incidentally, the question does not mention the GL version, but since it uses VAOs I have to imagine it is high enough to use interpolation qualifiers.